# MySQL stored function returning object instead of integer

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-functions

I need a function in mySQl that returns me an Id form a chat room table. Here is my function "get_room_id" :

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE room_id INT(11);
    DECLARE user_id INT(11);

    SET room_id = 0;
    SET user_id = get_user_id(in_user_uid);

    SELECT `id` INTO room_id FROM `room`
    WHERE `user_id`     = user_id
        AND `type`      = in_seller_type
        AND `site`      = in_site_domain
        AND `sellerid`  = in_seller_id
    LIMIT 1;

    IF (room_id > 0) THEN
        RETURN room_id;

    ELSE
        INSERT INTO `room` (`user_id`, `sellerid`, `site`, `type`) VALUES (user_id, in_seller_id, in_site_domain, in_seller_type);
        SET room_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO `participant` (`user_id`, `room_id`, `joined`) VALUES (user_id, room_id, NOW());
        RETURN room_id; 

    END IF;
END
```

that is returning this object in my NodeJS code :

```
[ RowDataPacket {
'get_room_id(\'13442692f82fdb4cf91919b1e3378fe4b79ec1bc\', \'mydomain.com\', \'pro\', \'5\')': 1 } ]
```

instead of an INT(11) with value 1 (we can see it at end of the object).

Does someone have a solution ?
Is my syntax wrong ?

Comment: I precise that when I return the room_id with LAST_INSERT_ID() it works, The issue occurs when I get room_id from the SELECT statement.

Comment: @rahpuser: The `into` keyword in the SELECT statement is *not* creating a new table. That's not a problem.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the syntax, aside from the  part that's missing... `CREATE FUNCTION get_room_id(in_user_uid VARCHAR(40), in_site_domain VARCHAR(40), in_seller_type VARCHAR(30), in_seller_id INT)`. What is being returned by the (unshown) query **`select get_room_id('1344...','mydomain.com','pro','5')`** is a normal resultset. I don't think your issue is anything to do with the function, aside from the unfortunate column name in the result of the query that calls the function. Assign a column alias to that in the query, to get a "simpler" looking result set.

Comment: Also, try testing your code with a simpler query, with no call to a function, e.g. **`SELECT 42 AS answer`** and you'll see the issue has nothing to do with the function.  As a more obtuse test, try assigning a complicated alias name to the column..  **`SELECT 42 AS \`myfunction('fee','fi',fo','fum')\``**  Compare the result from that to what your query is returning.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but my problem is that with SELECT I have a recordset and I get an integer in the ELSE with LAST_INSERT_ID. I want only the Integer value. Isn't it possible ?

Comment: To get only an integer value returned, you would have to use something other than a `SELECT`. For example, a `CALL` to a stored procedure. But to have the value of an `OUT` parameter returned, you would need a node.js module (MySQL database driver) that provides support for bind variables.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call your function like this (in SQL):

```
select get_room_id(...) as room_id
```

your code will probably return a nice object `{ 'room_id' : 1 }` which should be easy to manipulate inside your code.

From the point of view of Node, SELECT returns more than just one data value. It also returns the name of the column that was selected, and everything gets packaged into an object. Using aliases for awkward columns will help you get an easy-to-work with object.

Comment: +1 for recommending the addition of the column alias to "simplify" the name of the column in the result set.

Comment: What I want is no recordset (object)... I want the Integer as I expected in the function declaration. Not possible to ?